# Create Percentage on Two Fields using Count on 3

Tags: mysql, count

Suppose I have a clothing inventory table with Type,Color,Size and I do a group on those three fields to get the count of each but then want to do get the percentage of each size for each Type and Color. I made a sql fiddle with the original count(*) for the three fields and wonder if I can then return the % for Size per each Type and Color.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a4d/4

For instance in the sql fiddle shown I get the following for Black Pants:

- Pants,Black,Large,5
- Pants,Black,Medium,5
- Pants,Black,Small,10

whereas I'd want

- Pants,Black,Large,5,25%
- Pants,Black,Medium,5,25%
- Pants,Black,Small,10,50%

Comment: Can you provide your sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation and a join:

```
Select c.Type, c.Color, c.Size,
       Count(*), Count(*) / cc.cnt as proportion
from Clothing c join
     (select c.type, c.color, count(*) as cnt
      from clothing c
      group by c.type, c.color
     ) cc
     on cc.type = c.type and cc.color = c.color
group by c.Type, c.Color, c.Size, cc.cnt
having Count(*) > 1
```

It is unclear how the outer `COUNT(*)` condition fits into the total, so I left it out of the subquery.

Comment: This seems to work well when applied to the actual table though it didn't seem to need the last 'cc.cnt' in the final group thank you. Not sure if I can post follow-up Q here but since it is minor: I want to now return only those results where cc.cnt is <1 (type/color that has more than one size) but neither cc.cnt<1 or proportion <1 works. It returns null set.

Comment: @MarkH . . . Not needed `cc.cnt` in the `GROUP BY` is a MySQL (mis)feature.  As for your other question, perhaps the `<` should be `>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could `cross join` your query with a query selecting `count(*)` from the entire table, and divide the counts to get a percentage:

```
SELECT     Type, Color, Size, COUNT(*), COUNT(*) / total * 100 AS percentage
FROM       Clothing
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Clothing) t
GROUP BY   Type, Color, Size
```